# Is == in PHP a case-sensitive string comparison?

Tags: php, string-comparison

I was unable to find this on php.net. Is the double equal sign (`==`) case sensitive when used to compare strings in PHP?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Yes, `==` is case sensitive.

You can use [`strcasecmp`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) for case insensitive comparison

Answer (score 21):

Yes, but it does a comparison byte-by-byte.

If you're comparing unicode strings, you may wish to normalize them first. See the [`Normalizer`](https://secure.php.net/normalizer) class.

Example (output in UTF-8):

```
$s1 = mb_convert_encoding("\x00\xe9", "UTF-8", "UTF-16BE");
$s2 = mb_convert_encoding("\x00\x65\x03\x01", "UTF-8", "UTF-16BE");
//look the same:
echo $s1, "\n";
echo $s2, "\n";
var_dump($s1 == $s2); //false
var_dump(Normalizer::normalize($s1) == Normalizer::normalize($s2)); //true
```

Comment: +1 for insight that it's not really string comparison (it's binary comparison).  Hence it's technically not case-sensitive (Although in 99.999% of cases it behaves just like it)...

Answer (score 12):

Yes, `==` is case sensitive.

Incidentally, for a non case sensitive compare, use [`strcasecmp`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php):

```
<?php
    $var1 = "Hello";
    $var2 = "hello";
    echo (strcasecmp($var1, $var2) == 0); // TRUE;
?>
```

Answer (score 9):

`==` is case-sensitive, yes.

To compare strings insensitively, you can use either `strtolower($x) == strtolower($y)` or `strcasecmp($x, $y) == 0`

- [strtolower()](http://php.net/strtolower)
- [strcasecmp()](http://php.net/strcasecmp)

Answer (score 2):

`==` is case sensitive, some other operands from the php manual to familiarize yourself with

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `==` is case sensitive. The easiest way for me is to convert to uppercase and then compare. In instance:

```
$var = "Hello";
if(strtoupper($var) == "HELLO") {
    echo "identical";
}
else {
    echo "non identical";
}
```

I hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

You could try comparing with a hash function instead

```
  if( md5('string1') == md5('string2') ) {
    // strings are equal
  }else {
    // strings are not equal
  }
```