# case insensitive comparing in PHP

Tags: php, case-insensitive, string-comparison

Is there an operator in PHP that allows incasesensitive comparisons?

Instead of doing the following:

```
if (strtolower("A") == strtolower("a") )
```

I guess I'm looking for something like:

```
if ^("A" == "a")
```

Where `^` tells php to ignore the case based comparison.

Yes, I do have a wild imagination. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506706/is-in-php-a-case-sensitive-string-comparison

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`stricmp`](http://php.net/strcasecmp)

```
if(!strcasecmp('a', 'A')) echo 'strings are equal';
```

Comment: why do you need the ! in there?

Comment: @AverageJoe: Because `strcasecmp` returns 0 iff both strings are equal (ignoring the case). Otherwise it returns either +1 or -1, depending on which string is "smaller" (if you were to sort them) – check the docs

Comment: so it's better than typing the ==0 thing. saves in typing. i can't say readibility wise, it's the best thing but sure it saves typing. on the other hand, ==0 thing does not read well neither. it's php! it's always a hard language to deal with. thank you knittl.

Comment: The not operator (`!`) and `== 0` are _mostly_ equivalent. In this case it comes down to personal preference or project policies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strcasecmp`](https://www.php.net/strcasecmp) for this. Just check that it returns 0.

```
if (strcasecmp("A", "a") == 0) {
    // yes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php `strcasecmp`

```
if (strcasecmp("A", "a") == 0) {
    echo 'OK';
}
```

Thanks

:)

Answer (score 0):

[`strcasecmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php)